# Is it Possible to Subscribe to the CircuitBreaker Opening Event in Hystrix?

Tags: java, hystrix

For unit testing I would like to be able to subscribe to Hystrix events, particularly should there be an event when a circuit breaker opens or closes.  I looked around for examples and it appears that the work around is to tap into the metrics stream and monitor the circuit breaker flags.

Since Hystrix is build on RxJava I thought there should be a subscription interface for events somewhere.  Is there an easy way to subscribe to these type of events in Hystrix?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like there are events you can consume: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring

Comment: @Jocke Thank you, I saw these as well but I was looking for something more granular so I could subscribe to a specific action vs a general category of events... at least, that's how I understood these events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write Custom event notifier and registered it in HystrixPlugins. have look on below code.

```
public class CircuitBreakerHystrixEventNotifier extends HystrixEventNotifier{

    public CircuitBreakerHystrixEventNotifier(){

    }

   public void markEvent(HystrixEventType eventType, HystrixCommandKey key) {
        //here write code based on eventTypes.
    }
}
```

You need to registered this CircuitBreakerHystrixEventNotifier in hystrix, see below

```
HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerEventNotifier(getCircuitBreakerHystrixEventNotifier());
```

Comment: I found the event notifiers but it wasn't clear which event type to monitor.  Would you know?

Comment: For circuit opened you can use SHORT_CIRCUITED(full list is in enum HystrixEventType ), but not sure about closed event. Actually, me too looking for same, will post here if I get something.

Comment: Interesting, looks like SHORT_CIRCUITED is a boolean flag and also the event type.  Does that solve the problem or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, you can track Circuit open event on this event type.