# Pause/Resume JMS Listener Using Hystrix Circuit Breaker

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jms, hystrix, circuit-breaker

We have a JMS listener that pull the messages from MQ and save them in database. My question is what is the best way to pause the JMS Listener temporary while db is down and resume it again after some time.

My thought is using Spring Circuit Breaker around the db operation to monitor its health and fallback to an error handler method. This will help to avoid waiting for db timeout every time. However, the listener still is pulling the messages and try to save them which is wasting CPU and network.

Is there any way to handle the circuit breaker commands events like: open/half-open/close? Then I can write the code to **stop** JMS when circuit-open event happens and **start** JMS when circuit-half-open event happens.

Or what is the best practice to temporary pause a JMS listener when a dependency is failed?

Note: We are using Spring Integration message-driven-channel-adapter for the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, after checking the code for Hystrix Circuit Breaker library, I realised that firstly there is not any mechanism to notify Circuit state changes. Secondly, even if the events were there it wouldn't solve my issue. Because, Half-Open state is reached with the first attempt (service call) after the sleep window (when the circuit is open). while, for my case when JMS Listener is stopped there won't be any next attempt/call.

Eventually, I developed a custom circuit-breaker library that starts a timer/scheduler when opening the circuit and moves the circuit to half-open state automatically when the timer (sleep window) triggered.

Answer (score 2):

JMS listener is a `Lifecycle` bean and so as JMS inbound channel adapter in Spring Integration. That means they have `start()/stop()` methods, thus allowing you to stop consuming messages without stopping the application context.

With regard to a circuit-breaker, I am going to assume you're talking about one of the spring-cloud services. If so then you simply need to inject JMS listener or adapter into it's implementation and call it's `start/stop` methods. But that primarily meant for introducing circuit-breaker distributed microservices which also implies service-discovery and other advanced features.

If you're only running a single application context with spring integration (SI) to do the circuit-breaker you may want to benefit from the internal SI support described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#circuit-breaker-advice).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, JMS Listener has stop/start method but the question is how to integrate it with Hystrix circuit-breaker. I found that there is a way to get notified of Hystrix event, but there is not an event-type for when it moves to "half-open" state:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957791/is-it-possible-to-subscribe-to-the-circuitbreaker-opening-event-in-hystrix

Comment: I am not sure why you care about half-open. When DB connection is not available I am going to assume there will be some failure (exception). If you wrap that in Hystrix command you'll have an option to define fallback operation which is where you'll stop the JMS listener. At that point the messages will stop coming. When DB connection reappears you re-start the listener and everything is back to normal.  Come to think of it you actually don't even have a case for circuit-breaker as everything I just described is achievable without circuit-breaker and simpler.